# Unable to stream logs from a docker container in Amazon EC2 AMI to Cloudwatch logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I am running a docker container on Amazon EC2 instance using Amazon AMI, I used docker awslogs driver to stream logs from the container to cloudwatch. It works fine and I see the logs in Cloudwatch but if I restart the container, the logs are not being sent to Cloudwatch. If I stop and start the container once again, it works.

Any help on why the docker awslogs driver fails to upload logs when I restart the container is helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally attached a volume in docker to stream the log file in the container to the ec2 instance using '-v /var/app.log:/var/log/app.log' and sent it to cloudwatch using cloudwatch agent